# java.lang.noclassdeffounderror with libgdx and Android studio on the androidLauncher

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, libgdx, noclassdeffounderror

I imported a package of my own called server (the logic of my program) and was going to use libgdx for the graphics/cross platform. The desktop launcher works fine but when I run the android launcher I get this nasty error referring to my own library.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 187
              Process: com.mygdx.game, PID: 8093
              java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: server.Point
                  at server.Shape.<init>(Shape.java:9)
                  at server.T.<init>(T.java:7)
                  at server.Stack.<init>(Stack.java:28)
                  at server.Logic.<init>(Logic.java:14)
                  at com.mygdx.game.GameLoop.create(GameLoop.java:43)
                  at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceChanged(AndroidGraphics.java:275)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1511)
                  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1239)
```

any help would be great

Comment: Please show your build.gradle file

Answer (score 0):

I solved it!

It was because I was using java.awt.point in the android build. So I basically wrote a new point class, replace it, and then cleaned my project. Everything works now